# How do I distinguish the blank line?

Tags: java

I want read text file.  The contents of the text file are as follows:

```
A_market  
apple 1000  
orange 2000  
grape 1600

B_market  
apple 900  
orange 2100
```

Each market cannot know in advance the number of each fruit.
Each market will be separated by blank lines.

```
while (inFile.hasNext()) {
    String markerName = inFile.next();
    while (inFile.hasNexLine()) {
        Sting fruitName = inFile.next();
        int price = inFile.nextInt();
    }
}
```

How do I identify the blank lines in the text file?

Answer (score 2):

```
while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
   String line = inFile.nextLine();
   if (line.isEmpty()) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the condition

```
 if(fruitname.length()!=0)
```

to check the blank line.

Comment: There's also `isEmpty()`, which is a bit cleaner. Also `If` should be lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Path path = Paths.get("attachments/abc.txt", "");

List<String> list = Files.readAllLines(path,Charset.defaultCharset());
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
{
    if(list.get(i).isEmpty())  //or length()==0
        System.out.println("empty line at " + (i+1));
}
```